# How to do WHERE clause in UNION and LEFT JOIN?

Tags: join, mariadb, union

I am trying to do a `UNION` on 4 tables to get the ID's from each table, WHERE the USER_ID = `$_SESSION['uid']`
I will explain each query to give you an idea of where I came from, and where I am going.
The first query works fine, the problem: only `ID's` of each record. I need to left JOIN to get each records corresponding data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_questions
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_qualify_requests WHERE type = 'Prequalified'
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_download
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_upload
WHERE uid=? GROUP BY bid_id

$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
```

In the second attempt I add a left join. This query works fine, however it lacks the `WHERE` clause that specified the user ID.

```
SELECT 
bid_id.bid_id,//BID ID's  
b.title,
u.name
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_questions
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_qualify_requests WHERE type = 'Prequalified'
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_download
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_upload
) AS bid_id
LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.bid_id = bid_id.bid_id
LEFT JOIN users u on b.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY bid_id
```

If I try to add the `WHERE` clause in there, I get an error saying the column does not exist.

```
SELECT 
bid_id.bid_id,//BID ID's  
b.title,
u.name
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_questions
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_qualify_requests WHERE type = 'Prequalified'
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_download
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_upload
) AS bid_id
LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.bid_id = bid_id.bid_id
LEFT JOIN users u on b.uid = u.uid
WHERE bid_id.uid=?
GROUP BY bid_id

$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
```

Is there a way I can add the `WHERE` clause that applies to every inner query? I am sure I could add a separate `WHERE` in each query and bind a param for each. Or maybe I select UID and bid_id from all tables then select only the UID out of that table? I want the optimal performance option as this DB will be quite large. Any ideas?

Comment: what mysql version?  why a left join on users?  does the row in users sometimes not exist?

Comment: the user row always exists, because the USER must post the BID.

Comment: Add your WHERE to each subquery (4 times). This will work faster than UNION all rows then apply WHERE to combined rowset.

Comment: Surely you want `u.uid = ?`, not `bid_id.uid=?`?

Comment: Distinct is not a function, it removes entire duplicate rows, the parentheses after it do nothing, your only column in the subquery, which is a union of 4 queries, is bid_id. Chop the code down to the first subexpression that doesn't return what you expect, say what you expect & why, justifiying by referencing authoritative documentation. Don't try to sove your overall goal when you don't know how the parts work. For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] Clarify via edits, not comments. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question per post. PS There's no "optimal" unless you define it.

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt, the `WHERE` clause is only enacted on the final `SELECT` of all the UNIONS ... i.e. only on:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bid_id) FROM bids_documents_upload WHERE uid=? GROUP BY bid_id
```

In this, the `GROUP BY` is also redundant as the `DISTINCT` keyword will do the same thing.

In the second attempt - your INNER QUERY can stand alone, so if the `WHERE` clause was valid over the `UNION` then it can reside inside the brackets.  You have not stated where you added the `WHERE` clause to get the error message that you report.  If it was outside the INNER select then of course it doesn;t exist as you only return `bid_id` from the UNION statements - no ```uid`` is included.

You will need to expand on the information provided - at least the schemas of each of the tables involved in the `UNION`s as this would drive what the INNER query needs to be before joining it back to the `bids` table and possibly also the `users` table.

As you are working on a single `uid` it may be better to do a single lookup on the `users` table to extract and store the `name` for the `uid` in a variable rather than joining to the table.

If you added the additional information then you may have more success in getting a solution.

Comment: I just updated the question to demonstrate where clause insert